# [Symfony 4][Doctrine 2] queries on array field

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine

My question is simple, I want to query data stored with doctrine as array field (PHP serialized object), using something other than `'LIKE %xx%'` because the data I have is like this:

```
    a:4:{i:0;i:2;i:1;i:4;i:2;i:5;i:3;i:1;}
```

Which after unserializing gives this array: `[2,4,5,1]` So, the problem while using `'LIKE'` is that it confounds between keys and values, then something like this:
`Like '%3%'` will return a result because 3 is the key of the latest value.

I find it a little weird that I found nothing in the doctrine's or Symfony's documentation!

Comment: Would [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) or [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There's no good way to query serialized data unless the database supports it natively (e.g. recent postgres + JSON).

`LIKE` and similar approaches (`REGEXP`) can be a quick fix and might work if you know for sure that there cannot be any other data serialized in that field, but they are unreliable and in my experience: not worth the trouble.

If it's a one time job, get the data into PHP, let PHP parse them, use `in_array`.

If it's a feature you want to add in general, the earlier you refactor the serialized field into a separate table with a foreign key, the happier you will be in the long run. Using doctrine's array type is something you should only do if you're very sure that you're not going to need to query that field.